# Conditional expectation conditioned on function of a random variable

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $X, Y$ be continuous, real valued random variables, and let $f$ be a measurable function such that $f(X)$ is again a random variable.

How would the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y|f(X)=f(x)]$ look like in integral form and how could I write it in terms of a distribution of $X$ rather than a distribution of $f(X)$?

That is:
$\mathbb{E}[Y|f(X)=f(x)] = \int_{\mathcal{Y}} y \, d\mathbb{P}_{Y|f(X)=f(x)}(y)=... $

So I would like to rewrite this in terms of e.g. $d\mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(y)$. How can I do that?

1. would I need the change of variables theorem for that?
2. which conditions does $f$ have to meet?
3. can I somehow rewrite this with the help of the indicator function?

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Replace $X$ by the variable $f(X).$  Apply your favorite definitions and formulas for conditional expectation.

Comment: But can I not rewrite the integral of the expectation conditioned on $f(X)$ in terms of an integral that only depends or involves the variables $X$ and not $f(X)$ any more?

Comment: Let me repeat, then: replace $X$ by $f(X).$  *Name this new variable "$X.$"*  You are now in a familiar textbook situation.  Thus, with the *sole assumption that $f(X)$ is also a random variable,* (a technical condition that is ensured when $f$ is a measurable function), you need no new theorems, etc.

Comment: Thank you, yes that makes sense and seems straight forward. However, what I would like to do is to write it somehow like this $\int_{\mathcal{X}}\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\mathbb{I}_{\{x:f(X)=f(x)\}}\frac{f_{X, Y}(x, y)}{f_X(x)}dydx$. I guess this formula is wrong, but I would like to rewrite the expectation somehow like this as a double integral (if possible), integrating over $\mathcal{X}$, the image space of the RV $X$.